# Determining relative path in Perl Module

Tags: python, perl, perl-module

First Module:

```
package Compute;

our $sort_script= "/app/scripts/python_script.py";
```

Second Module:

```
package ProcessRestart;
use Compute;

# This perl module is also in /app/scripts/
# host1.com is an argument or script parameter 

$returnMsg= `$Compute::sort_script host1.com`;
```

Above is an example of a perl module I have written. It calls the python script from other modules and pass it in the necessary arguments/parameters.

I have tried removing typing the actual path of the script and replacing it with "./python_script.py" but it does not seem to work.

I have tried printing the directory upon running the script using Cwd, it points to my home directory.

What other ways can I try to have a relative path to the script?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking how to execute a script that's located in the same dir as the module that executes it.

```
use Path::Class qw( file );

my $qfn = file(__FILE__)->dir->file('python_script.py');
```

or

```
use File::Basename qw( dirname );

my $qfn = dirname(__FILE__) . '/python_script.py';
```

or

```
use Dir::Self qw( __DIR__ );

my $qfn = __DIR__ . '/python_script.py';
```

`__FILE__` is a special token that returns the path to the file in which the symbol is located.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to perl. For use Path::Class qw( file );  Do I have to replace "file" with the file name?

Comment: No, it's the name of a function that creates a Path::Class::File object. Each snippet I posted can be used as-is to produce a usable path in `$qfn` (which is short of "qualified file name", meaning an absolute or relative path to a file). As I explained at the bottom, `__FILE__` will automatically be replaced with the path to the file in which the snippet resides.

Comment: Thanks. 1 more question if you don't mind.With regards to, use File::Basename qw( dirname ); How can I use it to get the parent directory?

Comment: The parent of what? To obtain a path to the directory that contains the file contains the code being executed, use `dirname(__FILE__)` (as I've shown).

Comment: I noticed dirname(__FILE__) returned as /app/scripts/lib I would like to only have /app/scripts